# How can I get my trained model ready for production

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I successfully trained my model using the sklearn's multiple linear regression. This is the code I used:

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('C:\\mylocation\\myfile.csv')
dataset2 = pd.get_dummies(dataset)
y = dataset.iloc[:, 31:32].values
dataset2.pop('Target')
X = dataset2.iloc[:, :180].values

#Split the dataset
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

#Feature Scaling
#from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

#sc_X = StandardScaler()
#X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
#X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

According to validation results my y_pred is a reasonable predictor. Now, I would like to take into production this model and I am wondering what are reasonable steps to apply this model to the whole dataset I have stored and future datasets if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first cross validate your pipeline, making sure that you get an homogeneous `y_pred` result.

Then you can retrain a model with the same parameters on your full dataset. Pickle the model as well as any preprocessor tools, and reuse them to predict on new data.

Comment: Thanks. Could you possibly give a few pointers on how to do this specifically?

Comment: Check `pickle`, that's the only thing you need.

Comment: Ok thanks. Could you provide a bit more clarity about what I have to do to retrain the model with the same parameters, based on the code I have above?

Comment: Yes, sure, just use directly `X` and `y` instead of the training set. But first you need to cross validate your (hyper) parameters.

Comment: Sorry but could you show me with a bit of code?

Comment: `regressor.fit(X, y)`

Comment: So only switch that line and make the last one `y_pred = regressor.predict(X)`?

Comment: Well, there is no test set anymore for your final model. You need then to use new data to get a prediction on it, and if you did a proepr cross validated analysis, you should get an error similar to your cross validated test error for your new predicted data.

Comment: Apologies I have edited my comment above.

Comment: No worries. If `X` is your new data, then yes, this will work.